# Making RGB color in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I am using RGB values of a color from Photoshop and using the same in Xcode the values are.Color-R-160,G-97,B-5...the color in Photoshop appears yellowish but in Xcode when I used

```
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:160 green:97 blue:5 alpha:1] ;
```

the color appears whitish.

Why this difference is happening?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

### Objective-C

You have to give the values between 0 and 1.0. So divide the RGB values by 255.

```
myLabel.textColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:(160/255.0) green:(97/255.0) blue:(5/255.0) alpha:1] ;
```

**Update:**

You can also use this macro

```
#define Rgb2UIColor(r, g, b)  [UIColor colorWithRed:((r) / 255.0) green:((g) / 255.0) blue:((b) / 255.0) alpha:1.0]
```

and you can call in any of your class like this

```
 myLabel.textColor = Rgb2UIColor(160, 97, 5);
```

### Swift

This is the normal color synax

```
myLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: (160/255.0), green: (97/255.0), blue: (5/255.0), alpha: 1.0) 
//The values should be between 0 to 1
```

Swift is not much friendly with macros

> Complex macros are used in C and Objective-C but have no counterpart
>   in Swift. Complex macros are macros that do not define constants,
>   including parenthesized, function-like macros. You use complex macros
>   in C and Objective-C to avoid type-checking constraints or to avoid
>   retyping large amounts of boilerplate code. However, macros can make
>   debugging and refactoring difficult. In Swift, you can use functions
>   and generics to achieve the same results without any compromises.
>   Therefore, the complex macros that are in C and Objective-C source
>   files are not made available to your Swift code.

So we use extension for this

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(_ r: Double,_ g: Double,_ b: Double,_ a: Double) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

You can use it like

```
myLabel.textColor = UIColor(160.0, 97.0, 5.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: What is the point of having a fractional color value? I cannot output any such value in Photoshop?

Comment: @nipponese: The reason for using rational color values is that it makes channel multiplication easier and faster. It's used for blending for example. `UIColor` represents a RGB(A) color using the [0..1] range. The calculations above are just scaling each channel from the [0..255] range to the [0..1] range. In Photoshop you use the [0..255] range (e.g: `rgba(160, 97, 5, 1)`), or its hexadecimal equivalent (e.g: `#A06105FF`).

Comment: I just need the macro :)

Comment: The alpha value should also be in the range of 0-255 in my opinion.

Answer (score 25):

You already got the right answer, but if you dislike the `UIColor` interface like me, you can do this:

```
#import "UIColor+Helper.h"
// ...
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRGBA:0xA06105FF];
```

UIColor+Helper.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (Helper)
+ (UIColor *)colorWithRGBA:(NSUInteger)color;
@end
```

UIColor+Helper.m:

```
#import "UIColor+Helper.h"

@implementation UIColor (Helper)

+ (UIColor *)colorWithRGBA:(NSUInteger)color
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((color >> 24) & 0xFF) / 255.0f
                           green:((color >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.0f
                            blue:((color >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.0f
                           alpha:((color) & 0xFF) / 255.0f];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 5):

Yeah.ios supports RGB valur to range between 0 and 1 only..its close Range [0,1]

Answer (score 5):

**Color picker plugin for Interface Builder**

There's a nice color picker from Panic which works well with IB: http://panic.com/~wade/picker/

**Xcode plugin**

This one gives you a GUI for choosing colors: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eblRfDQM0Go

**Objective-C**

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(160/255.0) green:(97/255.0) blue:(5/255.0) alpha:1.0];
```

**Swift**

```
let color = UIColor(red: 160/255, green: 97/255, blue: 5/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

**Pods and libraries**

There's a nice pod named `MPColorTools`: https://github.com/marzapower/MPColorTools

Answer (score 0):

The values are determined by the bit of the image.
8 bit 0 to 255

16 bit...some ridiculous number..0 to 65,000 approx.

32 bit are 0 to 1

I use .004 with 32 bit images...this gives 1.02 as a result when multiplied by 255