# RGB colors of Xcode differ from Photoshop RGB

Tags: xcode, rgb, photoshop

When I use 255 150 0 in Photoshop the orange differs from the orange I get in Xcode using the RGB sliders. Can anyone help me why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use The RGB colors between 0 - 1

```
myLabel.textColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:(160/255.0) green:(97/255.0) blue:(5/255.0) alpha:1] ;
```

See This Link :

[making real rgb color in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379009/making-rgb-color-in-xcode)

Answer (score 3):

If you are setting RGB color from IB then you have to change the RGB type by tapping on settings button to Generic RGB:

[image]