# set color of any UI in RGB format

Tags: objective-c

When I am setting color of any UI like text field place holder color or Slider maximum and minimum tint color in RGB format, It is not showing any color but just like a clear color. When I am changing red color of RGB to 0 it is showing mix color of green and blue. But as I increases value of Red in RGB up to 1 it is going to be faint and at 1, it is invisible. my code is 
To set slider color

```
 [_sliderSpeed setMaximumTrackTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:181 green:217 blue:255 alpha:1]];
```

To set text field placeholder color

```
NSAttributedString *pin = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Add pin" attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:103 blue:169 alpha:1] }];
self.pin.attributedPlaceholder = pin;
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like this

```
 [_sliderSpeed setMaximumTrackTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(181/255.0) green:(217/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1] ;//set your color here
```

For Ref:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10379026

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: @NituWarjurkar  welcome