# How can I find the background color code for the "LaunchScreen.storyboard"?

Tags: ios, xcode

I changed the background color of the *LaunchScreen.storyboard*, but the color does not appear as it is supposed to, So I need to divide by 255. Where can I find the code for the `backgroundColor` of *LaunchScreen.storyboard* view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way you can do this is through Interface Builder.
The LaunchScreen.storyboard does not accept code.

Sometimes, when you change the Launchscreen, for a bug, it is not updated in real time. Reboot the device you can solve.

[Xcode Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhAO0.png)

Comment: Ok, so what if I changed the background color of the Main.storyboard view? will I be able to change the code somewhere?

Comment: I want to use code similar to this, but I want to change the view color not the label:
myLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: (160/255.0), green: (97/255.0), blue: (5/255.0), alpha: 1.0) 
//The values should be between 0 to 1

Comment: @TheNewDeveloper, you can add a custom color in the Attribute Inspector of the LaunchScreen.storyboard, but not code. Deleting the existing app from the simulator, or device, will force the latest iteration of the launch screen to build, if it is still not appearing correctly.

Comment: @Marcy The problem is that changing the color through the attribute inspector will give me different shade than the one I selected in Photoshop, so I am trying to use the solution in this post to solve the problem:
[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379009/making-rgb-color-in-xcode

Comment: Are you comparing the colors using the same display? I don't see how setting a custom color in IB would differ from programmatically setting the color such as in the link. But you could add a regular storyboard and set it as the launch screen, to use code.

Comment: When you click in Custom to change the background color a small screen appears to customize the color. 1. Click on the third icon the `Colors Palettes`. 2. Click on the settings icon at the side of the `drop-down box` and the new. 3. A new item will appear,, click on the color picker in the bottom and then click on the custom color you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you are asking. The `LaunchScreen.storyboard` storyboard is displayed before your app code is run, so you can't write app code to alter that storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

you can open LaunchScreen.storyBoard or the appLaunch screen if you use another screen as a splash one in VScode or any editor you use
and change the color code on it

change the values to the colors you want